# Adding confidence bands to a scatter plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I'm trying to add confidence bands to a scatter plot with a regression line in R. I have the scatterplot with regression line complete. For the confidence bands, I have found the code:

```
ggplot(Plastic.Hardness.Data, aes(Y, X)) + 
geom_point() + 
stat_smooth(method = lm)
```

This seems to work, however, I need to use 98% confidence bands. How do I specify the confidence level?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `level = 0.98` to `stat_smooth()`. Like this:

```
ggplot(Plastic.Hardness.Data, aes(Y, X)) + 
geom_point() + 
stat_smooth(method = lm, level = 0.98)
```